# My Mac has Python3 and 2.7 installed. How do I uninstall Python3 but keep 2.7?

Tags: terminal, python, macos

I installed python3 a few days ago, but I need to use version 2.7 for school. When I run in terminal, it shows like below:

```
RandeMacBook-Pro:~ ranshu$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
RandeMacBook-Pro:~ ranshu$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

I tried to uninstall python3 in Finder but my Mac still used python3.

How do I cleanly uninstall version 3?

Comment: how did you install python3?

Comment: This question needs an update. Specifically, the path to python  is needed to determine if it’s an os installed tool or add on. Specifying a version of macOS would help as well since the steps to remove system software change quite a bit recently.

Answer (score 6):

There’s no need to uninstall python3 if you remove the executable from your path. Just keep calling the older version or use a tool like `pyenv` to juggle which is preferred if you don’t like or care to control your path.

You may have multiple versions of Python 3.x installed on your Mac. To uninstall all of them, first check which are installed:

```
brew list | grep python
```

Let's say you have 3.9 and 3.7 installed. To remove 3.9, run this command:

```
brew uninstall python@3.9
```

To remove 3.7, just replace `3.9` with `3.7` above.

Answer (score 5):

`rmtree` verb is not available in the default install of Homebrew.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ brew rmtree python3
Error: Unknown command: rmtree
```

You can use `uninstall` verb as:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ brew uninstall python3
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5... (5,102 files, 102.9MB)
MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ python3
-bash: python3: command not found
MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

However, `rmtree` can be installed by executing the following:

```
$ brew tap beeftornado/rmtree
$ brew rmtree <package>
```

Using `rmtree`, one can cleanly and completely remove a package installed from Homebrew, along with all of its dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you installed python3.

If you installed python3 via the official mac installer(.dmg), you need to remove it from Finder -> applications. Just drag the python3.x icon to the Trash icon on the bottom right corner. If you had installed several versions of python3, you may find more than one python3.x icons, each one corresponds to a single python3 version instance, you may choose which one to remove.

If you installed python3 via a package manager like brew, you need to use the remove command from the package manager, for example, brew uninstall python3.

Answer (score 3):

Try

pyenv:

To get all installed versions:

```
pyenv versions
```

To get uninstall specific version

```
pyenv uninstall 3.5.0
```

Similarly to install specific version

```
pyenv install 2.7.10
```

Comment: I used this method, installing pyenv,  but I am wondering if I should therefore uninstall Python3 from brew?  (leaving the 2.7 of course)

Answer (score 2):

If you used homebrew to install python3 the command to remove it is

```
brew rmtree python3
```

You should be able to have both versions installed. Call your scripts via

```
 python myScript.py
```

This will use your python2.7. If you want to use python3 the command would be

```
python3 myScript.py
```

Answer (score -2):

If the python3 location is in /usr/bin/python3 then you won't be able to delete it directly, macOS may throw an error like “Operation not permitted” or “read only file system” etc, because macOS mounts the system files as a read-only partition and use a mechanism called system integrity protection (csrutil).

To remove the file you need to do the the following steps,

1. Reboot the Mac OS into recovery mode
2. Open disk utility
3. Unmount “Macintosh HD” and mount again
4. Open terminal from utilities
5. Run command 'csrutil disable'
6. Remove the file from 'rm /volumes/macintosh\ hd/usr/bin/python3'
7. Run command 'csrutil enable'
8. Reboot the OS again

Comment: This likely belongs on a different question. I’ll put this one on hold since the OP clearly explained they used homebrew to install python3