# How to make "python" command in terminal open python3 instead of python2.7 which comes with mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, python

Mac comes with Python2.7.

For a project, I need to use Python3.7.5. I installed it.

However, if I just type python in terminal, the 2.7 interpreter starts.

How do I make it so that when I type python, it opens 3.7.5 interpreter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type `python3` and you will be running the new version. How [you install can vary a bit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273774/my-mac-has-python3-and-2-7-installed-how-do-i-uninstall-python3-but-keep-2-7), but on the current macOS you don’t need to install anything as the stub exists. On any older os I recommend installing https://brew.sh as it has a very friendly on boarding and helps you set your PATH properly to run the v3 of python.

A [shell alias is an easy way to fix this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435517/) permanently.

```
alias python=python3
```

Comment: I did this and it works. However, if i quit the terminal, and start it up again, it resets to 2.7... what can I do to make it permanent?

Edit: fixed it by putting it in bash_profile.

Comment: Yes @DonCode - `brew doctor` will guide you to fix your path if needed. Then you can add the alias there, too

Comment: Put the line `alias python=python3` in your shell profile (either `.zshrc`, `.profile`, or `.bash_profile`) under your home directory. This will work every time you open a new terminal.